# How to reset the headless test db?

Tags: developer, civix, testing, cv

I'm using headless phpunit tests. I noticed that the first time I do this it pauses and says about installing schema for xxxx - a test database.

If you break stuff enough, you can end up with a corrupted/no-good test CRM database. How do you get a fresh one back?

I tried dropping the test database, but that just caused errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ah-ha!

In your test class edit the `setUpHeadless()` method which might look at first like this:

```
  public function setUpHeadless() {                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    // Civi\Test has many helpers, like install(), uninstall(), sql(), and sqlFile().
    // See: https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.testapalooza/blob/master/civi-test.md
    return \Civi\Test::headless()
      ->installMe(__DIR__)
      ->apply();
```

But pass `TRUE` to `apply()`, ie

```
  public function setUpHeadless() {                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    // Civi\Test has many helpers, like install(), uninstall(), sql(), and sqlFile().
    // See: https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.testapalooza/blob/master/civi-test.md
    return \Civi\Test::headless()
      ->installMe(__DIR__)
      ->apply(TRUE);
```

Ta-daa! And now your tests will run super slow as the schema will be reinstalled every time. But helps you out of  a spot, and you can of course remove that param.

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth noting that if you're using `civicrm-buildkit` to create your test sites (highly recommended) you can also rebuild a site with `civibuild reinstall`.

Comment: Using civi-buildkit is the only way I've gotten tests to run at all, as required files are not present in standards installs. I'm not sure a site rebuild would result in a schema rebuild (?) since I don't think any of the data used to create the comparison hash would have changed. I think I tried that once.

Comment: I didn't realize you needed a schema rebuild - for that you can always run `bin/regen.sh`, then do the reinstall.

Comment: I think what you're suggesting will rebuild the main schema of the civi-buildkit site. When you run headless (the default type) tests a separate new database is created; the original buildkit one is supposedly untouched. I'll check out that command though, thanks